# hide ribbon menu for workflow

Tags: workflow, ribbon, custom-actions

I want to hide the workflow button: Ribbon.List.Settings.ManageWorkflows

Which scope should the feature have (web or site)?

Now I try:

```
<HideCustomAction Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.List.Settings.ManageWorkflows">
</HideCustomAction>
```

on site scoped feature. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is XML to hide `ManageWorkflows` button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.List.Settings.ManageWorkflows" />
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Check [Walkthrough: Removing a Button from the Server Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408060.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! Can you check the link you provided? I can't open it.

Comment: sry. link updated

Comment: Is it possible to revert this operation (if I need this ribbon button in the future)?

Comment: Just retract solution and you have your button back.